# Install PyAudio - Python 3.4

Tags: pyaudio

Unable to install pyaudio from the package `python3-pyaudio_0.2.8-1_amd64.deb`
with the following error message:

> Dependency is not satisfiable: python3(<3.3)

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 where the default Python3 version is Python 3.4.

Is there a way to get this to work with Python 3.4 version  or my only bet is to downgrade to Python 3.3 ?

Answer (score 0):

If i did understand your question well, i recommend you check the following repository in github.

[pyAudioAnalysis Installation](https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis/wiki/2.-General)

Comment: Please provide the answer in the link on stackoverflow because links can become invalid over time.

Comment: i thought he could clone the repo and goes from there, since i can not give a proper explanation as the one documented in their repo. I promise next time i will do my best even though i lack knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Use pip install pipwin on CMD after that use pipwin install pyaudio on ur program

Comment: Please consider adding some description to your answer. :)